# Conditions to preserve Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, graph-laplacian

Let $L$ be a Laplacian matrix $L=D-A$ where $D$ and $A$ are the degree and the adjacency matrices. It is known that $L$ has (among others) the properties: $L=L^T$, $L\geq 0$ and $L1_n=0$, where $1_n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional vector with all entries equal to $1$.

Now I have the transformation $\bar L=WLW^T$, where $W$ is an $r\times n$ matrix, and then $\bar L$ is an $r\times r$ matrix.  We assume that $W$ is full rank.

**Q:** I would like to find (IF possible) necessary and sufficient conditions for $\bar L$ to be Laplacian. The difficult part is to check or find conditions on $\bar L 1=0$. We proceed as follows:

let us write $W=\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\\
\vdots\\
w_r
\end{bmatrix}$, $W^T=\begin{bmatrix}
w_1^T & w_2^T & \cdots & w_r^T
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $\bar L=WLW^T=\begin{bmatrix}
w_1Lw_1^T & w_1Lw_2^T & \cdots &  w_1Lw_r^T\\
w_2Lw_1^T & w_2Lw_2^T & \cdots &  w_2Lw_r^T\\
\vdots & & & \\
w_rLw_1^T & w_rLw_2^T & \cdots &  w_rLw_r^T\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus we have

$$
\bar L1_r=\begin{bmatrix}
w_1L(w_1^T+\ldots +w_r^T)\\
\vdots\\
w_rL(w_1^T+\ldots +w_r^T)\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This means that we have to solve $w_iL\alpha=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,r$ and $\alpha=w_1^T+\ldots +w_r^T$.

From the fact that $W$ is full rank, we know that $w_i$ and $\alpha^T$ are linearly dependent for all $i$. But I don't know how and where should I proceed. Do you think I can refine more the conditions on $W$?

Comment: You call this a Laplacian matrix, but the graph Laplacians I am familiar with have additional properties.  e.g. For the laplacian of a connected graph, the kernel consists entirely of the one vector (and its multiples).  That could impact your conditions.

Comment: Indeed, even more, I may assume (generically) that $\ker L=\left\{  1_n\right\}$. However, concluding things from there is where I am stuck.

Comment: So then $L=L^T$, $L\geq 0$ and $L1_n=0$ is not your definition of a Laplacian matrix?  If not, can you specify the definition.  There are many "Laplacians" in use.

Comment: No, those are the principal properties that a Laplacian satisfies, in fact $\ker L=1_n$ is a consequence of $L1_n=0$ plus multiplicity assumptions. The definition of $L$ that I use is  $L=D-A$ where $D$ is a diagonal "degree" matrix and $A$ is an adjacency matrix. Sorry, my syntax was misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I'll demonstrate that a necessary and sufficient condition is 
$$LW^T1 = 0$$
when $r \leq n$.

> $\bar L$ is self-adjoint

Since $\bar L = WLW^T$ we have
$$(\bar L)^T = (WLW^T)^T = WL^TW^T = WLW^T$$

> $\bar L$ is positive semi-definite

We know that for all $v$, $\langle Lv, v \rangle \geq 0$.  We compute
$$\langle \bar L v, v \rangle = \langle WLW^Tv, v \rangle = \langle L(W^Tv), W^Tv \rangle = \langle Lu, u \rangle \geq 0$$
where $u = W^Tv$.

> $\bar L 1 = 0$ is equivalent to $LW^T1 = 0$

Consider
$$\bar L1 = WLW^T1 = W(LW^T1) = 0$$
Since $W$ is full rank (and $r \leq n$), the only way for $WLW^T1 = 0$ is for $LW^T1 = 0$.

I am unable to produce a better condition for a general $W$ than the one at the end of your post: $$WLW^T1 = 0$$

Comment: Checking again your answer, I think it is not true since $W$ is or size $r\times n$. Then, the equation $Wx=0$ has non zero solutions.

Comment: @PepeToro - Agreed.  I misused the $W$ has full rank condition.